# Query to fetch unique case no having program code with TS and AP?

Tags: sql, oracle

can any body help me ? 
Scenario: -
One table is there with caseno and program code,  I need to fetch case no having exact program code, 
Eg

```
Case no  program code
101          TS
101          AP
102          TS
102          OD
103          TS
103          AP
103          OD
```

So I need to fetch case nos only having program code `TS` and `AP`,
In this table it should return `101`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `avg` aggregation with `having` clause

```
with tab(case_no,program_code) as
(
 select 101,'TS' from dual union all    
 select 101,'AP' from dual union all    
 select 102,'TS' from dual union all    
 select 102,'OD' from dual union all 
 select 103,'TS' from dual union all    
 select 103,'AP' from dual union all      
 select 103,'OD' from dual    
)    
select case_no
  from tab
 group by case_no
having avg(case when program_code in ('TS','AP') then 1 else 0 end) = 1;

CASE_NO
-------
101
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/YPD73102)</kbd>

Comment: It's not feasible to write  with tab(    ),  as I have  provided   just a sample data for understanding,  in db millions of cases_no will be there. I am using Oracle as rdbms.

Comment: @RajanikantaPradhan it's just a sample, i.e. demonstration, just consider the select statement for your case.

Comment: Thank you,  got it,   any other approach do you have.

Comment: @RajanikantaPradhan welcome. Isn't this enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Tomorrow need to try,  as I don't have remote db access now.

Comment: with tab(case_no,program_code) as
(
 select case_no,program_code from from tablename      
)    
select case_no
  from tab
 group by case_no
having avg(case when program_code in ('TS','AP') then 1 else 0 end) = 1; IS this appropriate in my case ?

Comment: @RajanikantaPradhan sure, I think so from the shared info.